# Remove newpage after \tableofcontents, \listoffigures, etc. in book class

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, page-breaking

When using a documentclass of `book`, it seems there is a `\newpage` inserted after the `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures`. How can I suppress this? In `articles`, the following works. How can I get this layout with a `book`?

```
\twocolumn
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printglossaries
\onecolumn
```

Comment: This is because these document elements issue a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`, depending on the book mode (`onecolumn` or `twocolumn`). In fact, these elements are formatted as `\chapter*`, which issue the above commands. Do you have other `\chapter*` commands in your document?

Comment: I do not have any `\chapter*` commands.

Comment: @cmhughes' answer would do the trick. If you want to be complete, you could add `\let\clearpage\relax` as well. You didn't mention whether you're using a `oneside` or `twoside` `book`. The grouping restores the redefinition after `\endgroup`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could temporarily redefine `cleardoublepage`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} % generates a dummy document

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me :)