# Creating an abbreviations file

Tags: input, include, nomenclature

I'm new to the LaTeX scene as I've starting writing my thesis. I'm using a root `.tex` file and using `\include` to add in my chapters (etc). I'm also using `\nomencl` to add an abbreviations list. I'd like to have one central file that I can add abbreviations too and then add it to my final document. So I have manged to make that work but I can't get rid of the blank page created where I include my abbreviations file

abbrev.tex

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\section{}
\nomenclature{JOE}{Job Obselete Effort}%
\nomenclature{NHE1}{The human Na$^{+}$/H$^{+}$ exchanger isoform-1}%
\nomenclature{home}{Where the heart is}
\nomenclatenter code hereure{LaTeX}{better than sliced bread}%
```

root.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{report}
...
\begin{document}
...
\include{chapter1
\include{chapter2}
\include{abbreviations}
...
\end{document}
```

and just to make it really clear: everything (i.e. all abbreviations and abbreviation list are inserted correctly in the document) is working EXCEPT I get a blank page where `\include{abbreviations}` is. I know I can just add all the `\nomenclature{...}` lines at the end of a chapter file but it would be nice to have them in one place. I've also tried `\input' instead but it's exactly the same.

Comment: you could temporarily redefine `clearpage`, `cleardoublepage` as detailed in [remove-newpage-after-tableofcontents-listoffigures-etc-in-book-class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30747/remove-newpage-after-tableofcontents-listoffigures-etc-in-book-class)

Comment: Thanks @cmhughes! Nearly there. Using `\let\cleardoublepage\relax` and `\let\clearpage\relax` removes the extra page but it also seems to remove what ever page it is on. So if I put it in my final chapter at the beginning it removes the last page of text and my references. If I put it after the bibliography code it removes just the references. If I add it to the abbrev file it removes the nomenclature page. Without my entire document this might be hard but, where do I put it?

Comment: Testing some more it seems that `\let\cleardoublepage\relax` doesn't have any effect but `\let\clearpage\relax` deletes the page it's on

Comment: I also tried the complete block `\begingroup` `\let\cleardoublepage\relax` `\let\clearpage\relax` `\endgroup` but this has no effect (same as adding no code)

Comment: Try \input{abbrev.tex} instead of \include{abbrev.tex}.

Comment: Yes! That's it so really I didn't understand the page you linked to @cmhughes. I added my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

ok so the root file needed

```
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\include{chapter3}
\include{abbreviations} %or \input{abbreviations}
\endgroup
```

and in chapter3.tex I included

```
...
\bibliography{JabRef_new}
\bibliographystyle{bibsty}
\let\clearpage\relax
```

if `\let\clearpage\relax` is included in the root file before `\include{chapter3}` the pagebreak before the bibliography is removed.

Comment: In my opinion you should use `\input` instead of `\include`; the latter is more useful when writing the document, with the former you have no problem caused the implicit `\clearpage` issued by `\include`.

Comment: @egreg You're probably right. For some reason using `\input{abbreviations}` alone without the `\begingroup` etc doesn't supress the page break. This might be because I'm using `\include{chapter3}` but if I use `\input` for all the chapters my individual chapter bibliographies are reproduced following every chapter. So although there may be a better practices way I don't want to mess up what is already working.