# Remove blank page between last chapter and appendix?

Tags: blank-page

I'm having this problem:

> last chapter
>       [annoying blank page]
>       appendix

I tried solving it by looking up for some answers here but nothing seems to work for me. Please help me. Thanks. (below is the code)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{etd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%\listoftables
\endgroup

\beginbody
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{chap_introduction}
\include{chap_review}
\include{chap_techbackground}
\include{chap_methodology}
\include{chap_recommendations}
\appendix
\include{appendix_BR2}

\include{vita}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you mock up a real [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that uses [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) for text filler?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I imagine you could use the same idea demonstrated in [Remove newpage after \tableofcontents, \listoffigures, etc. in book class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30747)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've made some changes like relocating the figures included in the appendix.

Comment: Your code does not compile even if I create dummy files for all of the `\include`s and change `etd` to `pittetd`. I get `\beginbody` as undefined. Also, unless you have departmental approval, `float` is not permitted and, even if you do, it is unsupported and likely to give 'unpredictable' output according to the documentation.

Comment: @clairecaceres So is it working now?